# factory pattern - invalid use of member in static member function

Tags: c++, factory-pattern

I'm new to this factory pattern in C++ and I was given the header yet while trying to implement one of the methods I am getting the following error:

Invalid use of member 'creationFunctions' in static member function

```
typedef Shape (*createShapeFunction)(void);
/* thrown when a shape cannot be read from a stream */
class WrongFormatException { };

class ShapeFactory {

public:

    static void registerFunction(const std::string &string, const createShapeFunction *shapeFunction);
    static Shape *createShape(const std::string &string);
    static Shape *createShape(std::istream &ins);

private:

    std::map<std::string, createShapeFunction *> creationFunctions;
    ShapeFactory();
    static ShapeFactory *getShapeFactory();
};


void ShapeFactory::registerFunction(const std::string &string, const createShapeFunction *shapeFunction)
{
    creationFunctions.at(string) = shapeFunction;
}
```

Comment: Looks like there are 2 patterns: Factory(but I found only Concrete one, there is Abstract factory, also Abstract product needed) and Singletone(I recognized it by private constructor - better do it protected, to allow sublcasses implement it if needed, and by static method - getFactory - but it should be public, or else how you are going to use it) ))

Comment: .... you are right about the getFactory.. as a homework i have to implement all those methods yet i'm really lost in this factory thingy ..

Comment: @Have you read the book: "Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software"? (authors : the so called the Gang of four) it contains detailed description of various groups of patterns and each pattern explained in depth with 2-3 examples

Answer (score 2):

You can't access non-static members of a class from a static member function. In your example the probably best idea would be to make all member functions non-static, except "getShapeFactory" which would then act as Mayer's singleton generator...

Comment: I see yet I cannot change the header. I have to leave it as my teacher gave it to me..

Comment: Then you'll have to make the data members static too. But I encourage you to add the mentioned alternative to your appointment. Even nicer solution is to use the gateway pattern

Answer (score 1):

One problem I see is that you are accessing a variable private to `ShapeFactory` from a static function. Static functions are not tied to a specific instance of a `ShapeFactory` so you cannot access non-static private variables. Another side effect of this is that `this` is not defined in the context of static functions. Each time you create an instance of `ShapeFactory` a new instance of `std::map<std::string, createShapeFunction *> creationFunctions` is created for each `ShapeFactory`.

I'm not very familier with implementing factories, but I think what you might want to do is make `std::map<std::string, createShapeFunction *> creationFunctions` static so that it can be accessed by the static member functions of `ShapeFactory`. A private constructor like what your header file contains suggests that `ShapeFactory` will be a singleton and so if you really want it to be a singleton, making `std::map<std::string, createShapeFunction *> creationFunctions` by static should be okay.

Edit based on requirement to not modify header:

You can have `registerFunction` get a pointer to a factory from `getShapeFactory()`. Notice how I create a new pointer that is not a const pointer. This allows you to insert the pointer into the map. I'm not sure how best to handle `shapeFunction` as this method seems like it may not be ideal, but I'm not 100% sure what this function is supposed to do.

```
void ShapeFactory::registerFunction(const std::string &string, const createShapeFunction *shapeFunction)
{
    createShapeFunction* shapeFuncPtr = new createShapeFunction(*shapeFunction);
    ShapeFactory* factory = getShapeFactory();
    factory->creationFunctions.insert(std::pair<string, createShapeFunction*>(string, shapeFuncPtr));
}
```

Have a static variable within `getShapeFactory` that creates a factory. The value of this variable will get saved each time this function is called so after the first call of this function the same pointer will be returned each time. This has to be implemented in a .cpp file that contains your header.

```
ShapeFactory::getShapeFactory()
{
    static ShapeFactory* factory;
    if (factory == NULL)
        factory = new ShapeFactory();
    return factory;
}
```

Comment: I have tried your code yet it says: Assigning to 'mapped_type' (aka 'Shape (**)()') from incompatible type 'const createShapeFunction *' (aka 'Shape (*const *)()') - in the register function

Comment: Oh sorry I ignored the consts when I was writing my answer. I'll fix it.